# Whole image cloud cover for LC8_SR?

Tags: metadata, landsat-8, google-earth-engine, reflectance, cloud-cover

I need to filter the LANDSAT/LC8_SR image collection using an assessment of ***total cloud cover in the entire scene*** of each image.  i.e. each image in the collection is "in" or "out" based on a threshold of cloud cover for the whole image.  In the TOA collections I can easily do this using 'CLOUD_COVER' from the metadata, but the surface reflectance collection does not have this metadata attribute.  I have tried using reduceRegion to find the sum of cfmask=4 over the 'cfmask' layer, but this returns a value and I don't know where to put that value so I can use it to filter the images.

```js
// Load a Landsat 8 ImageCollection for a single path-row.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_SR')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('wrs_path', 23))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('wrs_row', 38));
// use wrs feature collection to establish region to assess cloud cover
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1_RZgjlcqixp-L9hyS6NYGqLaKOlnhSC35AB5M5Ll')
    .filter(ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.eq('PATH', 23),
    ee.Filter.eq('ROW', 38)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the way to go:

```js
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1_RZgjlcqixp-L9hyS6NYGqLaKOlnhSC35AB5M5Ll')
.filter(ee.Filter.and(
ee.Filter.eq('PATH', 23),
ee.Filter.eq('ROW', 38)));

var geom = ee.Feature(fc.first()).geometry()

// Load a Landsat 8 ImageCollection for a single path-row.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_SR')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('wrs_path', 23))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('wrs_row', 38));

// Compute CLOUD_COVER and add it as an image property
var mapper = function(img) {
  var cfmask = img.select("cfmask")
  var clouds = cfmask.eq(4)
  var per1 = clouds.reduceRegion({
             reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
             geometry: geom, 
             scale: 30,
             maxPixels: 1e13}).get("cfmask")
  var per = ee.Number(per1).multiply(100)
  return img.set("CLOUD_COVER", per)
}

// Print size before filtering
print("before", collection.size())

// Apply function
var col = collection.map(mapper)

// Filter by 10% or less
var filtered = col.filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER","less_than", 10)

// Print after filtering
print("after", filtered.size())

// Filter by 90% or more
var withclouds = col.filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER","greater_than", 90)

// Add layer to see that it works
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(filtered.first()),{bands:["B5","B6","B4"],min:0, max:5000}, "less than 10")
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(withclouds.first()),{bands:["B5","B6","B4"],min:0, max:5000}, "greater than 90")

Map.centerObject(geom)
```

But, I think it'd be better if you use the image footprint instead:

```js
// Compute CLOUD_COVER and add it as an image property
var mapper = function(img) {
  var cfmask = img.select("cfmask")
  var clouds = cfmask.eq(4)
  var per1 = clouds.reduceRegion({
             reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
             geometry: img.geometry(), 
             scale: 30,
             maxPixels: 1e13}).get("cfmask")
  var per = ee.Number(per1).multiply(100)
  return img.set("CLOUD_COVER", per)
}
```